# Display Data from List object based on condition

Tags: java, list, object, arraylist

Can someone please assist on how to get the data from the below List 
based on user input value. I have mentioned the List records and the output data how its required to be displayed.. Appreciate if someone can help with details.

```
 **List< Object > alist** **==>** clouds={all=88}, coord={lat=32.16329, lon=12.52859},, **name**=Yafran, rain={3h=0.255}, weather=({description=light rain, icon=10d, id=500, main=Rain}), wind={deg=356.5, speed=3.96}}
clouds={all=89}, coord={lat=42.06329, lon=12.52859},, **name**=Pheonix, rain={3h=0.255}, weather=({description=heavy rain, icon=10d, id=500, main=Rain}), wind={deg=356.5, speed=3.96}}
clouds={all=96}, coord={lat=12.06329, lon=12.52859},, **name**=Atlanda, rain={3h=0.255}, weather=({description=light rain, icon=10d, id=500, main=Rain}), wind={deg=356.5, speed=3.96}}

I want output from this list based on user input… say if user enter **name** : **Yafran**, I should display the details in my UI as below.
**Name** : Yafran
**Weather. Description** = light rain
**Wind.speed** = 3.96
**Wind.deg**=356.5
**Coord.lat**=32.12
```

I have n records in the list and the data should fetch the corresponding row from the list of objects based on user input.

Comment: Your info doesn't look like Java to me. What does your program look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list and you want to search based on some key .Two solution possible

1.Iterate over list and match one by one with key If present return the result.

2.If your key is in sorted order you can use binary search.

One thing If you are only want use single key you can use HashMap complexity of  search is constant.